# ssh X11 forwarding after forgetting -X

Tags: ssh, x11-forwarding

Is there a way to tell an already-running ssh session to forward X11 connections, if you've forgotten to supply `-X` on the command line? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really; you'll want to disconnect and reconnect.

If you want to forward X sessions most of the time, then consider a bash alias such as:

```
alias ssh="ssh -X"
```

You can also set it permanently in `~/.ssh/config` by setting `ForwardX11 yes`.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I tried setting up port forwardings from within ssh by using the escape character `~` after a newline, but I had no way to set up the Xauthority stuff. The main reason I haven't made such an alias until now is that every time I use `ssh -X` on Mac OS X, it delays for several seconds while it starts Xquartz at the beginning of the session. Since I don't usually need X I prefer not to forward it all the time.